# Trying to rename several account types at once based on current displayName

Tags: powershell, active-directory, rename, identity

This morning some awesome people helped me make a script to move user accounts based on their displayName to a certain OU. I tested and it worked. I cannibalized the script to make another one that will rename the same accounts based off of the same criteria. I've gone through several errors but basically it all boils down to "I am having an identity crisis!". I can't seem to figure out exactly what I need to input as the `$Identity`. Here is what I have:

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Renames = @(
  @{
    Filter = 'DisplayName -like "*Supply*"'
    NewName = "Supplies"
  },
  @{
    Filter = 'DisplayName -like "*Accountant*"'
    NewName = "Accounting"
  }
) | ForEach-Object {New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $_}

$OriginOU = "OU=Test,OU=Standard Users,OU=Domain Users,DC=com"

foreach ($Rename in $Renames) {
  Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OriginOU -Filter $Rename.Filter -Properties displayName |
    Where-Object {($_.Enabled -eq 'True') -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*DontTouch*')} |
    %{Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName {$_.DisplayName -replace '(.EPSILON ).+',"`$1$Rename.NewName"}}
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `-Filter` parameter for `Get-ADUser` only accepts strings, not arrays of strings. This may be your issue.

Comment: I was able to use the entire thing on another script all the way down to the last pipeline. Instead of Set-ADUser it was Move-ADUser. When it comes to Renaming the displayName, it is giving me an error stating that the 'Identity' parameter cannot be null.

Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the current object variable (`$_`) if you have `Set-ADUser` read directly from the pipeline. And since `Set-ADUser` apparently doesn't play nice with scriptblock arguments, you have to put the statement in a loop:

```psh
... | % { Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName ($_.DisplayName -replace '(.EPSILON ).+',"`$1$($Rename.NewName)") }
```

Note that if you want to expand object properties inside a string you have to put `$Rename.NewName` in a subexpression (`$()`), otherwise the whole object `$Rename` would be stringified and the string ".NewName" would be appended to it.

Comment: The second option I tried just now and it does update the display name, however, instead of replacing the display name after "EPSILON" with the correct information, it has this inside of the display name now     $_.DisplayName -replace '(.EPSILON ).+',"`$1$move.ReName"

Comment: The first option does the same. So basically they sort of work, just the information they are changing in the display name is putting the code instead of the results.